# TextField moves up when keyboard appears and scrolling enabled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I am using textfield with scrollview. Whenever keyboard appears, scrolling gets enabled and textfield moves up. But there is one issue, if I scroll my textfield, then click on another text field, it does not move up.

Please suggest.

Comment: post some code.How you did.

Comment: try TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView... This will handle all the things. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a scrollView , this will be best for you. Use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). Its very easy to use.

drop the `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m` and `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h` source files into your project, pop a `UIScrollView` into your view controller's xib, set the scroll view's class to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`, and put all your controls within that scroll view. You can also create it programmatically, without using a xib - just use the `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` as your top-level view.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the text field coordinate system into Scroll view coordinate system. Use the below code

```
-(void)rearrangeView{
    // previous

    if (txtActiveField == txtUsername) {
        CGPoint pt;
        CGRect rc = [txtUsername bounds];
        rc = [txtUsername convertRect:rc toView:scrollViewLogin];
        pt = rc.origin;
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y -= 40;
        [scrollViewLogin setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
    }
    else if (txtActiveField == txtPassword) {
        // [self.txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
        CGPoint pt;
        CGRect rc = [txtPassword bounds];
        rc = [txtPassword convertRect:rc toView:scrollViewLogin];
        pt = rc.origin;
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y -= 40;
        [scrollViewLogin setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark- UITextField Delegate
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    txtActiveField = textField;
    //txtActiveField.placeholder = @"";
    [self rearrangeView];

    return YES;
}
```

Here txtActiveField is instance variable of type UItextField